# disable screen record with sound in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-windowmanager, screen-recording

I am trying to disable screen record and screenshot in my flutter app and I already did using **flutter_windowmanager** package.

my problem is with screen recording, the sound of the video inside th app is still running and recorded by screen recording !

**any suggestions for also preventing sound record ?**

Answer (score 1):

No.  If your app is playing loud enough the microphone can hear it, it can be recorded.  There's no way to prevent that-  algorithmically canceling out sound from one source in an audio recording like that would be difficult, if not impossible.  Nor would it really buy you all that much-  they could always just hold an external mic up to the phone (they can also just capture your app with a second camera, which makes removing video recording also of limited use, if done to prevent a user from recording).

The one thing you could do is claim the mic yourself and not give it up.  But that would be annoying to anyone actually using your app.  And wouldn't rpevent capture with an external device of course.

Comment: yes you are right. but in IOS I already do it because there is a flag to check if the screen recording is runnning or not, so when it is running I set the volume to zero and it was useful trick. in android there is no such flag to do that. I need any indication about detecting screen record